# Can't pass array of objects to controller by jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I tried to pass array of objects to controller by `jQuery Ajax`, but result is `null` in `ASP.NET 5.0`.

My data array is what send to `controller:  regions`.
Data constructor is defined in `BoundingBoxModel` class.
This is my `ajax` function:

```
$("body").on("click", "#onClick", function () {
            var regions = [];
            var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('ui-draggable'));
            arr.forEach((tagele) => {
                var region = {};
                region.Height = tagele.offsetHeight;
                region.Width = tagele.offsetWidth;
                region.Top = tagele.offsetTop;
                region.Left = tagele.offsetLeft;
                regions.push(region);
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/GenCode/Addregions',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({'regions': regions}),
                success: function () {
                    alert("pass")
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, json, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
```

So this is my BoundingBoxModel:

```
 public class BoundingBoxModel
    {
        public int BoundingBoxId { get; set; }
        public double Top { get; set; }
        public double Left { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my action method. It's defined in `GenCodeController`.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddRegions(List<BoundingBoxModel> regions)
    {
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult(this.Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(regions), System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
         return result;
    }
```

My result is null:
[image]

I don't understand why it's happened. Can you help me?

Comment: You're sending an object, should you be sending an array instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues that I can see -

1. I am not sure if you explicitly written this logic but your region object will always have last value of arr because you declare your variable inside loop.
2. If you are trying to create an array then you should declare your region variable like - var region = []; .Right now it is an object.
3. You are trying to pass an object and accepting a list in webservice. Either remove the list in parameter in AddRegions service or pass a Array from ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by deteting `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` line in ajax code.
Using this line make the array of **region**'s type change to string so  when i get data in Controller problem was happened.